# How to get rid of lock screen in Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, lock-screens

Lately, instead of just being shut down my Samsung Galaxy S2 shows this screen (see screenshot).

How can I get rid of it? I don't want to see this screen ever again.
Somehow it appears only while I'm driving my car

**Update(10/8/2015):**

This screen appears **ONLY** whike I'm driving my car and the **phone is connected to charger**

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to just disable the lock screen completely? Here's how to do it:

1. Open your settings.
2. Go to Security and open your lock screen settings.
3. If you have a code or password set for your current lock screen, enter that code and continue.
4. Choose *none* as your lock screen option.
5. Lock your phone and unlock it again, it should open up your phone straight away and not show a lock screen.

([source](http://support.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II_4G.how_to_turn_off_the_screen_lock_on_my))

Comment: Thanks I did what you told me but it still appears while I'm driving my car  and the phone is connected to charger.